# C# AWS SQS Read all messages without deleting

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I want  to read all messages from queue in AWS SQS without deleting them , using C# , but I am only getting the single last message.

Here is the code

```
 ReceiveMessageRequest rmr = new ReceiveMessageRequest();
        rmr.QueueUrl = url;
        rmr.MaxNumberOfMessages = 10;
        AmazonSQSClient sq = new AmazonSQSClient("xx", "yy");
        ReceiveMessageResponse rmrep = sq.ReceiveMessage(rmr);
        ReceiveMessageResult rmres = rmrep.ReceiveMessageResult;
        //DeleteMessageRequest dmr = new DeleteMessageRequest();

        string msgid = "";
        string rephandle = "";
        XmlDocument xl = new XmlDocument();

        for (int i = 0; i < rmres.Message.Count;i++ )
        {
            rmrep = sq.ReceiveMessage(rmr);
            rmres = rmrep.ReceiveMessageResult;
            object y = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(rmres.Message[0].Body);
           int z= y.add();
           MessageBox.Show(z.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

A queue is not a database table; you can't just 'read all the messages'. You tell SQS you want some messages, it picks some and sends them to you; you can't ask it, or expect it, to iterate thru a unique list of messages in the queue and present them to you, it is not intended for that purpose.

If you read 1 or messages, and delete them (or put them in another queue), then eventually you can 'read all the messages', but as long as you don't delete any, its likely that you will keep getting served back some messages multiple times.

Comment: I agree it's not as simple as "receive all messages" but there are ways to do it depending on what is really needed.

If you have lower traffic, one option is to receiving max messages until you see a repeated key. (e.g. by keeping a Dictionary or HashSet)

If you have manageable number of actions to perform, another option is to do what you proposed, offloading from one queue to another (more of a streaming solution)

Comment: Understandable. Anyone seen AWS documentation that says this?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling receive message multiple times and thus are not seeing some of your messages.  Change your code to something like this:

```
AmazonSQSClient sq = new AmazonSQSClient("xx", "yy");
while (true)
{
    ReceiveMessageRequest rmr = new ReceiveMessageRequest();
    rmr.QueueUrl = url;
    rmr.MaxNumberOfMessages = 10;
    ReceiveMessageResponse response= sq.ReceiveMessage(rmr);

    foreach (Message message in response.ReceiveMessageResult.Message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message.ReceiptHandle + ": " + message.Body);
    }

}
```

NOTE:  If there are enough messages in the queue (the number depends on the queue and is not documented), you will not be able to receive any more because you will reach your maximum number of in-flight messages.

Another NOTE:   If this runs longer than your visibility timeout you will start receiving the same messages again.

Comment: i have hard time to parse message.Body and save to my database. any code sample help?